# Converting float into date with Python

Tags: python, datetime, floating-point, type-conversion, strftime

I'm currently struggling to understand the documentation of datetime.

I'm scrapping Excel data and with date it is giving me floats and I'd like to reconvert it to have date again.

My date format is hours:seconds and for example I'd like to have

`0.586111 --> 14:04:00`

`0.585417 --> 14:03:00`

I tried to use `date time.fromtimestamp(0.586111).strftime('%H-%S')`To reconvert it to the needed format but the output is `'01-00'` and I must admit in don't really understand what's going on and so what is wrong.

I know several questions about formatting date into float already have been asked but the other way is much rarer and I believe some people could make it clearer about the use of datetime in that case.

Thank you for your time and I hope that my problem was understandable.

Comment: What are your floats - what do they represent?

Comment: I have data from an excel file that I extract with (sowing) python and I put it in a data frame. Then when I render the data frame the line corresponding to a date that I had in excel (for example 14:01) is transformed into a float (here : 0.586111). Is that clearer or not ?

Comment: I edited it, it is in fact 14:04 and not 14:01 I was at the wrong line I'm sorry

Comment: The number looks like a fraction on one 24 hour time period. Ex `0.586111 * 24 = 14.066664`

Comment: It is close but the gap of 2 minutes is kind of bizarre I'd say

Comment: There is no real gap - .066664 * 60 = 3.99984, which is approximately 4.

Comment: Oh okay, didn't get it at the first glance

Answer (score 1):

The time is a fraction of a 24 hour period. There may be a built in function to convert that to a time. If not, try this:

```
def convert_time(t):
    t24 = t * 24
    hours = int(t24)
    # Discard integer part. Ex 14.066664 -> 0.066664
    t24 %= 1
    minutes = int(t24 * 60)
    t24 -= minutes / 60
    seconds = int(t24 * 3600)
    return datetime.time(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Output:

```
>>> convert_time(0.586111).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
'14:03:59'
>>> convert_time(0.585417).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
'14:03:00'
```

Comment: That seems to be a quick and fonctional solution. Thanks !

Comment: Actually, when I try to setup your code, it first ask me what is `m` so I believe its `minutes` and when I try to run it I get a ValueError : `day is out of range for month`

Comment: Do you know why it may not be working on my computer ?

Comment: Yeah, there were some typos. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

your solution with `fromtimestamp` is actually quite close, but it takes seconds, not fractional days, so convert to those first.

Alternatively, you can add the fractional days as a timedelta to a datetime object.

EX:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

sec_per_day = 86400
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(0.586111 * sec_per_day, tz=timezone.utc).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
# 14:03:59

print((datetime.min + timedelta(days=0.586111)).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
# 14:03:59
```

Note: don't forget to set tz to UTC, otherwise your local time's UTC offset might give you unexpected results. If you use `datetime.min`, time zones did not exist, so no worries there.